# How can get latitude and longitude from map into textview

Tags: android

I a new developer android  and I need to select latitude and longitude from google map.

I see old explanations people do it by Place Picker but now this is not work.because Place Picker was deprecated.

So how can I do that?

I need user can show google map and can select current location Then get latitude and longitude into textview in activity

anyone have idea about it?

Comment: You can use Place API instead of Place Picker. [doc](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro)

Comment: Do you have any example about it?

Comment: [Current place](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place) is what you need. And there is a tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial)

Comment: I see your suggestion But I did not know how I could select current location of user sorry my  brother

Comment: You can get current location with LocationManager.

Comment: I can get current locations no problem in that. But how can I choose the current location and select it  into textview?For example
As before, I could have done this through Place Picker.

Comment: You need to do that yourself. As far as I can see in docs. there is no ready form